# Subsets of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ disjoint with some of its shifts

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics, sumset

> Are there any descriptions of all subsets $X$ of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with the following property:  there exists $a\ne 0$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ such that $X$ is disjoint with $X + a = \{x + a \pmod n\mid x \in X\}$?

For example, for $n=5$, any set with 1 or 2 elements satisfies this property. I used to believe that the same holds for any subsets of size less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$, but for $n=6$, a counterexample can be easily constructed.

Probably there’s some well-known theorem about it?

Comment: Surely you noticed that a each proper subgroup $H$ works for $X$?  That fills out all the divisors of $n$, at least. And that the answer for $|X|>n/2$ is that $X$ cannot be disjoint from any shift.  So the question is reduced to subsets of size $\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ which are not divisors of $n$? Let me know if I'm making sense.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, it perfectly makes sense. I thought about subgroups too.

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $X-X=\{x-y\mid x,y\in X\}$.

Then: $X$ is disjoint from some of its shift iff $X-X\subsetneq\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Moreover:

> $X\cap (a+X)=\emptyset$ iff $a\notin X-X$.

For $(\Rightarrow)$: if $X\cap (a+X)=\emptyset$, then $a\notin X-X$, because otherwise $a=x-y$ for some $x,y\in X$, but then $x=a+y\in X\cap (a+X)$.

For $(\Leftarrow)$: if $X\cap (a+X)\neq\emptyset$, then $x=a+y$ for some $x,y\in X$, so $a=x-y\in X-X$. $\square$

---

Note that something similar holds for any group $G$. For $X\subseteq G$, $X\cap aX=\emptyset$ iff $a\notin XX^{-1}$, and $X\cap Xa=\emptyset$ iff $a\notin X^{-1}X$. (Here $XX^{-1}=\{xy^{-1}\mid x,y\in X\}$, and similarly for $X^{-1}X$.)

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, thanks. But I'm looking for more explicit description, like "if size of subset is less than n/2-1, then it satisfies condition". Your answer gives estimate that $|X| < \sqrt{n}$ is enough, but I believe it's far from optimal.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov Maybe I can say a bit more. If $n=km$ then there is $X$ such that $|X|=k+m-1$ and $X-X=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ (so $X$ is not "good"). Namely, if $H$ is the subgroup of size $k$ and $H,a_1+H,\ldots,a_{m-1}+H$ are its cosets then $X=H\cup\{-a_1,\ldots,-a_{m-1}\}$ does the job. So, for your question about $n/2-1$, if e.g. $n=4m$, then there is a "bad" set of size $3+\frac{n}{4}$, which is less than $n/2-1$ if $m>4$. But, it is an interesting question.